# php hmac sha512 signature not working/different then in python

Tags: python, php, hmac

I can't find the problem why the signature keys are different. I think it has to do with python, it need to have bytes for input. But the output of both language is total different. Not sure what's wrong with it.

```
API_SECRET = 'ErLN2dewKAfY5j4bHOIFQaCKogJIv8Tq'
```

**php**

```php
$digest2 = [
'486',
'GET',
'/orderlist',
'2.0',
'2020-01-29T11:45:47+01:00'];

print_r(base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha512', implode('', $digest2), $this->_API_SECRET, true)));
```

It wil give this code :

```
BsPgLClFDYl6oMRXkph7sz3opLeRAenzZ1w1X5fhiyDC4WVZViTvIWnLZWb1lQDVCRZ2/MkPT8irU9gax3m2Iw==
```

But when i tried to get the same code in python:

**python**

```py
digest2 =['486','GET','/orderlist','2.0','2020-01-29T11:45:47+01:00']
#token = hmac.new(bytes('API_SECRET'.encode("utf-8")), msg=bytes(''.join(digest2 ).encode("utf-8")), digestmod=hashlib.sha512).hexdigest()
digest = hmac.new(bytes('API_SECRET'.encode("utf-8")), bytes(''.join(digest2 ),"utf-8"), digestmod=hashlib.sha512).hexdigest()
return base64.b64encode(digest.encode("utf-8"))
```

It will give this code:

```
b'YThhNGI0ZGZkN2Q5YmJmNDg5OTJmNzE1NGZiMWQyMWExYzQyODU3OGUxNmQ1ZTRkZWUxOGViZTUxNmFhM2M4MGZmZTYzMTJhNWNhYWQ5MDg3NDdlMGQ0NDBmMDliZThkNTA2ODA1YTlkMjJmZGMwZTk3NjVkNmM2MmE0NTViMjQ=
```

Comment: You're passing `API_SECRET ` as string in python (`'API_SECRET'`). Try removing the quotes

Comment: You're enforcing raw output in PHP (via `hash_hmac()`'s last parameter, but then hex-encoding in Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You used base64 encoding on hexed string. Also you used `API_SECRET` as string instead of variable. Here's the working solution

```py
import hashlib
import hmac
import base64

API_SECRET = "ErLN2dewKAfY5j4bHOIFQaCKogJIv8Tq"
digest2 = ["486", "GET", "/orderlist", "2.0", "2020-01-29T11:45:47+01:00"]
digest = hmac.new(
    API_SECRET.encode("utf-8"),
    "".join(digest2).encode("utf-8"),
    digestmod=hashlib.sha512,
).digest()
print(base64.b64encode(digest))
```

Prints

```py
'BsPgLClFDYl6oMRXkph7sz3opLeRAenzZ1w1X5fhiyDC4WVZViTvIWnLZWb1lQDVCRZ2/MkPT8irU9gax3m2Iw=='
```